# Print an ajax response on a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which capture a click event of an anchor. Trigger a synchronous ajax function to get the response. Create a new window, write the response on the window and then print.

```
$('.print-grid').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    var response = $.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
    }).responseText;

    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write(response);
    w.document.close();
    w.focus();
    w.print();
    w.close();
});
```

The issue is because the print is empty but if remove the print the window render the content well. I think that's happening for the ajax call but I'm don't know how to figured it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CSS print media can avoid needing the new window also seems weird if you want to use a new window that you do not just open up the window with that URL!

Comment: Your AJAX function is completely redundant for two reasons. 1) the use of `async: false` 2) the fact you're opening the response in a new window. All you need to do is `window.open(href)` - or even just add a `target="_blank"` attribute on the `a` element, no JS required at all

Comment: now thats some very bizzare code right there o_O

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think you're missing that they are trying to print the new window. *Some* js is going to be required, just not this.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. In that case just a `window.print()` in the source of the page that you open in the new window is all that's needed.